# Possible to do client-side HTTP push?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, streaming, comet

Pretty much the opposite of server-side push, also known as [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)). I'm wondering if it is possible to use long lived HTTP connections to push information to the server.

Unlike a simple XHR, the connection would be kept alive and data would be streamed to the server at intervals, as the user completes actions etc.

Using standard technologies I don't believe this is possible, but I'm open to suggestions on possible exploitations or ingenious ways of accomplishing this. The purpose would be to complete low-latency data pushes to the server for fast and efficient one-directional streaming.

I'm not interested in using socket implementations with flash/java bridges because of the hassle of serving cross domain policies or getting the java signed. Crude hacks that work without additional dependencies are welcome. Preferably the solution would be done with javascript.

Comment: There's not much of a reason for this. Since HTTP1.1 reuses connections, once the first connection has been established, subsequent connections are incredibly fast; standard AJAX techniques solve this without any sort of issues related to maintaining long lived connections on the server, handling connection failures, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once saw a talk by the guy behind http://orbited.org/

It's a js library that uses standard technology to keep a connection open between the server and the client you can push stuff down.

Comment: Definitely along the lines of what I'm looking for, although would be much better if it would work over standard port 80.

Comment: It's a abstracted connection, though, that can end up using multiple HTTP requests (as many as one per message).  But it can be run on port 80 (just not, of course, on the same IP as a web server).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in one of a few ways ...

You can [keep a connection open](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connections) and do POST's, or I am sure it is possible to do a multi-part POST.

Comment: No, definitely not the same in any way.

Comment: The question is about sending some data, then sending some more data without beginning a new HTTP request -- ie. not just normal POSTs.

Comment: you can keep the connection open though, and is it possible to do a multi-part GET request? Either of those two scenarios would work just fine.

Comment: How? This is in JavaScript, so manually managing a socket is out.

Comment: Its harder to do, but its not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

this does it:
http://www.speich.net/projects/programming/firebug-testing.php

and look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))
and google around for 'x-mixed-replace'

Do your XHR on Firefox.  Must use it directly or grab XHR object to set funny fields. xhr.multipart=true and use the onload handler, not onreadystatechange.

The server should return data with mime type 'multipart/x-mixed-replace'.  plus a multipart separator.  flush to get the last bytes out for each salvo. I'm still trying to get it smooth.

Safari (~=chrome) can do it but the particulars are different.  Call your handler when readyState=3, not 4.  And every time the new text is Appended to resultText, not all alone.  Can't get anything to work on IE.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for bi-directional browser-server communication, you're probably looking for [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). See at the bottom of the Wikipedia article for available implementations.

Comment: Thanks :) This was 3 years ago, sockets weren't nearly as far along then as they are today.